# How to validate angular2-signaturepad?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, signaturepad

I am Using [angular2-signaturepad](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-signaturepad).

I am trying to validate the signature pad.
like this

```
savePad() {
      this.signature = this.signaturePad.toDataURL();
      if (this.signature != '' && this.signature == undefined) {
          //  this.signature = this.signaturePad.toDataURL();
          this.signature = '';
          let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
              message: 'You have to Signature first.',
              duration: 3000,
              position: 'c'
          });
          toast.present();
      }else{
      this.signaturePad.clear();
          let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
              message: 'New Signature saved.',
              duration: 3000,
              position: 'top'
          });
          toast.present();
      }
  }
```

this is my `savepad()` function.

I want this kind of functionality:

If signature pad is empty(save without signature) the toast want to come "You have to Signature first."
else it will save successfully.

Is this Possible to validate angular2-signaturepad ?

**or**

am I doing something wrong ?

if is possible then 
please guide me ..!!

Comment: What is suppose to be the problem ? Can you be more specific what you are trying to do ?

Comment: If signature pad is empty(save without signature) the toast want to come "You have to Signature first." else it will save successfully.

Answer (score 2):

You can check that the signature pad is empty or not by using isEmpty().
**Use**:

`this.signaturePad.isEmpty()`

This will return true/false.

Hope this will help.